# About global memory access method

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, nvidia

In general, for GPU, which accessing mode is faster (read data from a continous block of global memory)?

(1) for-loops with single or very small number of threads to read data from a block of global memory;

(2) let alot of threads, maybe from different blocks, to read data from global memory concurrently.

e.g.

```
if (threadIdx.x==0)
{
  for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)

     buffer[i]=data[i];//data is stored in global memory
}

OR:

buffer[threadIdx.x]=data[threadIdx.x];//there are 1000 threads in this thread block
```

Comment: It probably depends on what you want to do next.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the second should be faster generally. The Justification is followed:

There are two kinds of parallelism: Thread-Level Parallelism (**TLP**) and Instruction-Level Parallelism (**ILP**). Your first code (the loop) targets ILP and the second exploits TLP.

When the TLP is exploited, many memory requests are issued concurrently free of any control-flow dependencies. At this situation, hardware can take advantage of locality among threads to reduce total memory transactions (where possible). Moreover, hardware can serve the concurrent requests concurrently through L2-cache bank parallelism, memory controller parallelism, DRAM bank parallelism, and many other levels of parallelism.

However, in the ILP case, the existing control-dependency limits the number of concurrent issued memory requests. This is also true even in the case of loop-unrolling (hardware resources like scoreboard size and instruction window size limit the total outstanding instructions). So, many of the memory requests are actually serialized unnecessarily. Moreover, the hardware capability in memory access coalescing is not exploited.

Answer (score -3):

The Solution one is faster.Cause 1000 Threads is 1000 tasks actually witch share one task address space.The process scheduling of the OS must cost much resources of CPU.So the CPU always be interrupted.

If you do the thing in one task , The CPU always process one task.
And multi-core CPU can process better , But 1000 threads is too large.

Comment: This is a CUDA programming question. Your answer is completely irrelevant.